# How to display Guest and User account name

Tags: php, html

I'm currently developing the log-in system of this website. What I want to happen is, **you can visit the site as a GUEST** and **you can also log-in to an account**. (admin as my example)

I want to show *Guest* on the upper right of the page if you visited the website. However, if you're logged in from an account, the username is displayed also from the upper right. (I can already display the username. ) I used switch statement for this.

The *Guest* is there but I want to hide those notice messages. 
**I just want to hide those notices**
[image]
[image]

(^Username display)
Here's the code:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['started']) && $_SESSION['started']) {

}
?>

<li role="presentation" class="dropdown pull-right">
<a class="dropdown-toggle"  title="Profile" data-toggle="dropdown" href="" 
role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" style="cursor: pointer;" aria-
hidden="true"> <span class="caret"></span>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li role="presentation"><a href="">Settings</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="logout.php">Log out</a></li>
</ul>
 </li>

  <li class="pull-right"><a href="profile.php" title="Profile"><?php

   //echo  "";
switch ($_SESSION['user']) 
{
  case ' "'.$_SESSION['user'].'" ' =="":  //To display Guest
echo "Guest"; 

break;

case ' "'.$_SESSION['user'].'" ' != "":  //To display your username
echo $_SESSION['user'];
break;

default:
echo "INVALID";
break;
}

?></a></li>
```

Comment: Check if the session user array is set using isset(). This way it will not display the notices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
echo 'Hello, '.$_SESSION['user'];
}else{
echo 'Hello, Guest';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check that session is set or not.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
    switch ($_SESSION['user'])  {
        case ' "'.$_SESSION['user'].'" ' =="":  //To display Guest
            echo "Guest"; 
            break;

        case ' "'.$_SESSION['user'].'" ' != "":  //To display your username
            echo $_SESSION['user'];
            break;

        default:
            echo "INVALID";
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First check user session set or not.

Try below,

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
    switch ($_SESSION['user']) 
    {
        case $_SESSION['user'] == "":  //To display Guest
            echo "Guest"; 
            break;
        case $_SESSION['user'] != "":  //To display your username
            echo $_SESSION['user'];
        break;
        default:
            echo "INVALID";
        break;
    }
}
else{
    echo "INVALID";
}
?>
```

You can also remove notice from PHP.

```
ini_set("display_errors",0); // 0 : For Not Display, 1 : For display.
```